# The sourcearray is not long enough C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have following problem:
I try to send a bytearray from my PC to a device. Max data which can be sent is 59 bytes. Byte 1-4 are used for counting the packages which are sent. So total amount of bytes is 55 per package.

Now i get an error sourcearray is not long enough, even if the remaining bytes are mor than 55.

Anybody got an idea what my problem is?

```
uint RAW_DATA_SIZE = 55;
byte[] parameters;
uint byteCount = 0;
                
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0])+".hex");
Console.WriteLine(fi.Length);               // Size of the whole HEX data sent
TotalSentBytes = Convert.ToUInt32(fi.Length);   //Convert long to uint
uint dataSize = TotalSentBytes;
```

Comment: which line is failing here? it *sounds* like it is the `ASCII.GetBytes` - in which case: what is `content`? more to the point: why are sending the same `content` each time? also... it feels like maybe the first 4 bytes should depend on what we're *actually sending this time*? (this looks like a typical frame length prefix?). Was it your intention to send "the next up-to-55 bytes of `content`" each time? because: that isn't what your code does

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using `byteCount` as the `sourceIndex` argument of the `Array.Copy` method (see signature in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_)):

```
Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content), 0, parameters, 
       4 * sizeof(byte), remainingBytes > RAW_DATA_SIZE ? RAW_DATA_SIZE : remainingBytes);
```

I have replaced `byteCount` with 0, as you want to copy from the source array from its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i now have my answer.
I used Fileinfo to get my total amount of bytes to send.

```
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0])+".hex");
 Console.WriteLine(fi.Length);               // Size of the whole HEX data sent
 TotalSentBytes = Convert.ToUInt32(fi.Length);   //Convert long to uint
```

Now i get the length of the bytearray saved in the .hex file by:

```
byte[] contentOfBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content); //get content of hex-file
uint dataSize = Convert.ToUInt32(contentOfBytes.Length);  //get number of elements in the bytearray
```

Now i dont get any error anymore.